# Converting code from 2.7.10 to 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was finally able to get the recursion to print before I realized the way the professor had explained it was for 2.7 and we are supposed to be using python 3. So when I changed IDE over to 3.4.3 the code no longer works.

Any help on changing the syntax to work for 3 would be greatly appreciated I am just having no luck figuring it out.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    else:
        print("Computing fibonacci(%d) + fibonacci(%d)") % (n-1 , n-2)
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    print("Computing fibonacci(%d) + fibonacci(%d)") % (n-1 , n-2)
```

This is equivalent to `(whatever print returns) % (n-1 , n-2)`. `print` returns None, which doesn't support the percent operator. This explains the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'` error.

The percent operator needs to be next to the string, rather than next to the print function. The outermost parentheses pair needs to contain your arguments.

```
    print("Computing fibonacci(%d) + fibonacci(%d)" % (n-1 , n-2))
```

Comment: plus one for print returns None.